# Problems changing css properties of hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sorting, gridview

I have an asp.net gridview and have just added sorting to the columns. This has now obviously changed the column headers to links and they have changed to a blue colour but for some reason my modifications to change the colour of the links isn't working and they just wont pick-up the correct style.

Here is some CSS that I tried, I have tried it a few other ways too but wanted to test it using the most basic setup:

```
 a:link {
   color:white;
 }
 a:visited {
   color:white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` with Sachin's answer

```
a{
  color:white !important;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't pick it up I'm afraid.

Comment: @connersz then post your html and css

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div #something .gridview td a{
                                Color: red! important; 
                             }
```

Try to set style more specific to your anchor tag.